# DevExpress XPO or Telerik OpenAccess

Tags: devexpress, xpo, openaccess

I'm going to start a mid-sized project and planning to use a good ORM product. I'm going to use a code first approach.

I tried Entity framework, OpenAccess and XPO. I think we're going to buy XPO or OpenAccess. Do you have any suggestions about these products?

Thanks

Comment: what about nhibernate? are XPO and OpenAccess only options?

Comment: have a look at this http://ormbattle.net/

Comment: I will use Microsoft Entity Framework, thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, 
i decided to use Microsoft Entity Framework. Microsoft seems to be interested in ORM these days, and released the 4.3 version recently. Code Based Migration is covered in new version and they announced that v5.0 is on the way. Code based migration was my first priority.

I still could not get a good understanding about how latest versions of XPO and OpenAcces works, because most videos or walkthroughs are 2-3 years old. Entity Framework will be enough for me so i don't have to research others anymore even maybe others are better.

Answer (score 5):

OrmBattle hasn't been updated in quite a while. It would be a good idea to run the tests on your own for different products.

You also need to figure out exactly what you need from the ORM tool, as different tools excel in different areas.

Disclaimer: I work here at Telerik and would suggest you let us know what you need in a [forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx) thread. We will be happy to give you feedback on whether our product can help.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using XPO since the beginning of .NET! It very easy to learn has a huge community , the best support team in the market, great [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument1998) and hundreds of [samples](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=xpo&p=T4%7CP2%7C33&d=16) . In my personal opinion, those tests made by themselves was a clear advertising campaing for 'data objects.net'.
Also, the fact that numbers may vary more than two times in any directions between consecutive runs does not increase trust.
Most of the test scenarios tells next to nothing about how good or how bad that ORM is as an ORM -- best numbers in the tests are for BLToolki, which is not an ORM at all (in a common understanding of ORM).

Here is a related document for XPO in case you miss it that proves that XPO is even faster than native .NET http://web.archive.org/web/20040803195511/http:/www.devexpress.com/?section=/products/net/xpo/PerformanceComparisonXPOvsADO